# wxPython app becomes unresponsive on all threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

In my class that inherits wx.Panel, I have this method:

```
def KeyEventProcedure(self):
    while True:
        z = msvcrt.getch()
        if ord(z) == 27:
            self.OutputText("Stopping.")
            self.program_stopped = True
            print "IT'S WORKIIIIING"
```

And in the `__init__` method of my PanelClass, I have this:

```
self.program_stopped = False
keyThread = Thread(target = self.KeyEventProcedure)
#keyThread.setDaemon(1) //I tried with and without this call, makes no difference
keyThread.start()
```

And in many places in my app I have this check:

```
if self.program_stopped == True:
    self.program_stopped = False
    return
```

I know I can quit the whole app in the `KeyEventProcedure` method, but I don't want to quit the app, I just want the currently executing function to `return`. However when I start the app, no matter how many times I press `ESC`, it doesn't print and the currently executing operation doesn't return.

Comment: Start troubleshooting. Does `getch` get called? Does it return? What does it return?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it only goes trough `KeyEventProcedure` once, even tho it's `while True:`, it doesn't seem to crash or anything...and I'm not killing the thread prematurely anywhere

Comment: What is the last thing it does? Does it call `getch` and not return?

Comment: Right on program start, `KeyEventProcedure` runs once, the last breakpoint it hits is on `z = msvcrt.getch()`, then the function suddenly exits, but no error is printed.

Comment: Tried putting it in:

        `while True:
            try:
                z = msvcrt.getch()
                if ord(z) == 27:
                    self.OutputText("Stopping.")
                    self.program_stopped = True
                    print "IT'S WORKIIIIING"
            except:
                print sys.exc_info()`

To no avail

Comment: It's like as if `msvcrt.getch()` kills the thread instantly and exits.

Comment: IIRC `msvcrt.getch` will only work from applications with a console, not pure GUI applications, because the latter do not have propper input streams set up for them.  If you run your application from a command line with python.exe instead of pythonw.exe then you might be able to get input with `getch` if you first click on the command line window to give it focus, but that is still iffy since you are doing it from a thread.  Best bet will be to drop polling and `getch` and go with a fully event-driven approach as Mike suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is catch key presses, you should just use wxPython's built-in capabilities for that. Try binding to wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN or even wx.EVT_CHAR instead of using this Windows-only method. See the following:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/

Also, you should not try to access a wxPython program from a thread directly. If you need to update the UI from a thread, then you must use a wxPython thread-safe method, such as wx.CallAfter or wx.PostEvent. See the following for additional information:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Comment: But I want the keypress to be registered, even if something is constantly running on the main thread. It's just that `msvcrt.getch()` and `msvcrt.getwch()` both fail without any error or without any exception thrown...

Comment: @Mike- From the example in the first link I realized that key press event has to be bound to a widget like a button. Is it not possible to do the same with say the frame or the panel? Otherwise one would be required to bind key_press event to every widget in the frame...

Comment: You can bind to the panel / frame, but that only works if no widget has focus. The panel will always try to pass focus to one of its children, if it has a child that can accept focus. Otherwise, you might want to take a look at an AccleratorTable.